# Good *extensible* dictionary software?

Tags: vocabulario, vocabulario-técnico, recursos

I am looking for a software that could help me create my own dictionary (extension). While there are excellent dictionaries for Spanish out there both freely available on the web as well as commercial ones, those tend to be rather weak when one has to delve more deeply into a specific domain with its own specialized vocabulary.

Using search engines and sites like wikipedia it is possible to find the correct translations for rather special vocabulary. But I would like to save the results of such research in a form that would allow me to consult it later. For example, I just did a little research that came up with Spanish translations for expressions like *parallel computing*, *actor systems* and  *message passing*. So, is there any free or commercial software out there that could help me with that? It should, of course, have full-text search, and ideally allow me to organize entries into categories using tags.

My approaches so far have been

- a notebook (yes, a paper one...)
- all kinds of different programs like text editors, text processors, Excel, leading to my favorite so far:
- a mindmap using FreeMind, which gives me some limited search functionality and the possiblity to structure its content

*[By the way, I found [this paper](http://nuyoo.utm.mx/edi_anteriores/pdf/e0103.pdf) to be a good resource for Spanish vocabulary on parallel computation.]*

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE! We're all glad you're here. This question probably isn't really a very good fit for this site, as it appears to fall under the category of a "list" question (see [faq](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq))--that is, there could be multiple, equally correct answers.

Comment: Furthermore, it's not really a *Spanish*, per se, but more a software question, and as such I might suggest asking a similar question over at [Superuser](http://superuser.com/), with a slight rewording to ask for "How can I organize my personal dictionary entries?" rather than asking for a list of software recommendations.

Comment: [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) might be another place to ask, especially if you're interested in non-software answers.  But in an case, be careful not to make it a "list" question, as those are generally off-topic across the entire SE network. Please be sure to read their FAQ before posting there, too, to be sure this sort of question would be welcomed there.